# jQuery passing variables to object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a dynamic variable and I cant get it to work.

This code works, it returns the artist Kanye West through the API:

```
searchOptions = { name: 'Kanye West', fuzzy_match: true };
```

When I try to insert a string variable it doesn't work.

Like such:

```
var artistname = "Kanye West";
searchOptions = { name: +artistname, fuzzy_match: true };
```

How can I get it to work?

Please help! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `+`:

```
var artistname = "Kanye West"
searchOptions = { name: artistname, fuzzy_match: true };
```

---

You don't have JSON and it is not a problem of jQuery either. `searchOptions` is a normal JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `+`.  Here, that is called a unary plus, and it converts the string to a number, in this case `NaN`.

Comment: I think it will be `NaN` (that is what Google Chrome sys).

Comment: Thanks, @Felix.  Lot of PHP lately. ;)